# PCA -- principal component analysis formula issue

Tags: matrices, projective-geometry, matrix-calculus

Here is the formula about PCA (maximize the projected variance). My confusion is how to derive from formula 12.2 to formula 12.3?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean 12.2 to 12.3?

Comment: @kennytm, thanks for the correction. Yes, I have corrected it. Sharp eye and vote up. If you have any thoughts on my original question, it will be great. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\left( \mathbf u_1^T \mathbf x_n - \mathbf u_1^T \bar{\mathbf x} \right)^2
&= \left( \mathbf u_1^T ( \mathbf x_n - \bar{\mathbf x} ) \right)^2 \\
&= \mathbf u_1^T ( \mathbf x_n - \bar{\mathbf x} ) \cdot \mathbf u_1^T ( \mathbf x_n - \bar{\mathbf x} ) \\
&= \mathbf u_1^T ( \mathbf x_n - \bar{\mathbf x} ) \cdot ( \mathbf x_n - \bar{\mathbf x} )^T \mathbf u_1 \\
&= \mathbf u_1^T \cdot \underbrace{( \mathbf x_n - \bar{\mathbf x} ) ( \mathbf x_n - \bar{\mathbf x} )^T}_{n\text{-th term of }\mathbf S} \cdot  \mathbf u_1
\end{align}

Comment: Very smart kennytm, vote up and mark your reply as answer.